# Corona SDK - object:scale() scales object but width does not change?

Tags: lua, scaling, coronasdk

I've scaled my an object by .99 every frame for a certain amount of time. Then I scale it 1/.99 for the same amount of time. Due to rounding errors, the object ends up bigger/smaller instead of the same size. To fix this, I save the original width and height in variables and set object.contentWidth and contentHeigth equal to these variables whenever necessary. However, the object continues to grow or shrink and is never reset. When I print the original width and height variables, the content widths and heights, and the regular widths and heights, they're all the same value, as if the object was never scaled.

I assume the problem here is me misunderstanding the Corona SDK object functions and properties, so I didn't post any code. If it's not a misunderstanding, I'll post a simplified version of my code here; just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume:
If you're trying to scale back to original size.
You should scale it from `0.99` to `1.0`, not to `1/.99`.

Use function `object:scale()` for relative scaling
Use property `object.xScale,object.yScale` for absolute scaling.

Try it with absolute scaling.

Comment: The scale function is relative. Each time a scale of .99 is applied the image is shrunk to 99 percent of its size. Scaling with a value of 1.0 will do nothing. I guess I'll post some code to clarify.

Comment: @gsingh2011 let me try, will whip up a sample code and see how

Comment: Corona really should have specified the absolute vs. relative scaling difference in the documentation.

Comment: @gsingh2011 for your info: [here](http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/objectscale#comment-54251) they did talk about it. Those two syntax should do the same thing intuitively